# How enable private network for custom linux on contabo?

Tags: linux, network-interface

I have a private network on Contabo VPS

```
publicIP1 10.0.0.1
publicIP2 10.0.0.2
publicIP3 10.0.0.3
```

and when I used default Linux with cloud-init, contabo added private IP for me, but now I use Talos, so I need to add my private network self.

Any way to set it up?

P.S. I tried add:

```
network:
    interfaces:
      - interface: eth1
        dhcp: true
        mtu: 1500
```

Comment: Why not use `cloud-init` on your current Linux distribution to set the IP address the same way as your last distribution?  Otherwise, there is not information here to help you as you have not described which Linux distribution you are using or what network stack your distribution provides.

Comment: @GracefulRestart OK, I added information about Linux distribution, and more details